# Неизвестные ссылки из libcryptopp.a и возникающие проблемы при использовании Crypto++/cryptopp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Я скачал библиотеку [cryptopp](https://www.cryptopp.com/) используя `MSYS2` (до этого я безуспешно пытался подключить эту библиотеку когда я её скачивал отдельно, не через `MSYS2`, и я на этом прогорел, так как я работаю в `VSCode` и использую `MinGW`, тоже отдельно), после того, как я скачал эту библиотеку появилась следующая проблема:

```
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x1b7): undefined reference to `std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x254): undefined reference to `std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(files.cpp.obj):(.text+0x2e6): undefined reference to `std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<int>)'
a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: a:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib\libcryptopp.a(cpu.cpp.obj):(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `_setjmp'
```

Параметры компиляции для `MinGW`:

```
A:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.cpp -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lcryptopp -o A:\Andrey_dev\AES256_GSM_C++\test.exe
```

(все папки указаны правильно, и я не мог перепутать компиляторы для обычного Си и для С++)

Код программы брал [отсюда](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

В чем соль и как эту проблему решить?

Comment: Флаги со стандартными библиотеками в конец строки, после `-lcryptopp`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не помогло, увы. Кстати, без этих флагов, которые позволяют запускаться программе без каких-либо зависимостей все компилируется отлично. Это как? И мне нужна именно standalone программа, я не хочу с собой еще и пачку из DLL носить.

Comment: @user7860670 да, но мне нужна standalone прога, у меня нет желания таскать с собой еще и разные DLL

Comment: ¿А что-то еще ставилось, помимо этой библиотеки? Остатки чего-нибудь старого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам отвечу на свой же вопрос:

Нужно просто скачать Visual Studio 2019/2022 и следовать инструкциям из [этого видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XE4zEN-WKg), пердолинг с VSCode и линковками MinGW того не стоил.